# Захват и воспроизведение звука

Tags: аудио, linux

Народ, как работать со звуком в современном линуксе? Раньше это делалось через файл `/dev/dsp`, а теперь там вместо этого файлы controlC0,  hwC0D0,  pcmC0D0c,  pcmC0D0p,  pcmC0D1p,  timer. И никакой документации, примеров... Попытки работать с этими файлами как с dsp, через ioctrl() не проходят.  Я хочу анализировать звук, речь, и синтезировать звук, речь. Что делать?

Answer (score 2):

В современных Linux'ах никто не обращается к файлу /dev/dspXXX напрямую, а делают это через звуковой демон. На данный момент самый распространённый - pulseaudio. Есть езё esd и jack. Соответственно, читайте их документацию на предмет API.

Answer (score 1):

Через gstreamer можно. Я захват звука на python через gstreamer делал.